# How to dynamically initialize a component to an input field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I need to add a custom date picker to my input field. The input field is loaded as part of a form that is loaded via ajax. Every time the form updates, it is via ajax. I have tried binding the change as shown in the snippet below:

```
$('form').on('mouseover','.date_picker', function() {

      $('.date_picker').datepicker({'format' : 'mm/dd/yyyy'});
 })
```

The problem with the `mouseover` event is that it gets triggered too often and is possibly not the best way to work with touch devices.

So if I try to add an optimization to ensure that the `datepicker` is called only once and things work fine until I do an ajax update.

```
var firstTime = true;
$('form').on('mouseover','.date_picker', function() {

      if(firstTime){
          $('.date_picker').datepicker({'format' : 'mm/dd/yyyy'});
          firstTime = false;
      }


 })
```

What is the right way to bind things to elements that get loaded via ajax without relying on setting up things in the ajax callbacks?

Comment: So you want to bind event to the dom element after the form has loaded ?

Comment: After you update the HTML in your AJAX callback, run the code to initialise the datepicker: `$('.date_picker').datepicker({'format' : 'mm/dd/yyyy'});`.

Comment: I want to avoid doing this in the ajax callback. Have mentioned that in my question. The reason being, I'm doing this across a lot of forms that all extend a base template which has common code like this.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you should is to change the value of `firstime` back to zero:

```
$.ajax({
   /*

   */
   .success : function(){
     firstime = 0;
   }
});
```

of course the above solution works if `firsttime` is global enough to be known to both `$.ajax` and `mouseover`.

Edited:

You can set a global AJAX event handler to trigger a function when ever an ajax request is sent successfully in that page. You can add conditions to it to suit your application.

```
$.ajaxSuccess({
  success : function(){
    changeBackToValue(); // custom function
}
});
```

Or you can attach it to your form's container:

```
$("#form-container").ajaxSuccess({...});
```

Comment: I want to avoid doing this in the ajax callback. Have mentioned that in my question. The reason being, I'm doing this across a lot of forms that all extend a base template which has common code like this.

Comment: I always use a hidden input field to check the status-change. As the form is loaded you change set its value to 1, and after the ajax call you can then set it back to whatever value desired. You can also set a global `$.ajax` even listener to do something after each ajax call in the page. With this, you can access the last status-change from any where and at any time in a page.is it good?

Comment: I actually got things to work by using `ajaxComplete` which is a gloabl callback after every ajax request. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome. I appreciate if you accept mine as an answer, of course, if it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

What @Rory McCrossan said is good. But to answer you question "right way to bind things to elements that get loaded via ajax without relying on setting up things in the ajax callbacks?"

Assuming new DOM element is inserted into DOM,you can listen to DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument event as;

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', function(){
  /* add binding to the newly inserted element here */ 
});
```

What it does is, whenever there is a new dom element insertion happening under document, it fires 'DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument' event.

Or you can try [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery),

```
// selector: the selector to match against
// matchedFn: the function to execute when a new element is added to the DOM that matches
$(...).livequery( selector, matchedFn );

// selector: the selector to match against
// matchedFn: the function to execute when a new element is added to the DOM that matches
// unmatchedFn: the function to execute when a previously matched element is removed from the DOM
$(...).livequery( selector, matchedFn, unmatchFn );
```

I hope this answers your question @Pratik Mandrekar :)

Comment: I couldn't get `DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument` to work for me as expected but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this to work using `ajaxComplete` which is a global callback after any ajax request in the app.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event,request, settings ) {
                var firstTime = true;

                $('form').on('mouseover','.date_picker', function() {

                    if(firstTime){

                        $('.date_picker').datepicker({'format' : 'dd/mm/yyyy'});

                        firstTime = false;
                    }

                });
            });
```